I am new to Visual Studio and I am trying to build a data entry form for my SQL database table but I keep getting an error I dont understand
I have a winforms project in Visual Studio 2022. I'm trying to add a row to a database when the user clicks a button, but I keep seeing this error:

'Form1'does not contain a definition for 'button1_Click' and no accessible extension method 'button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found.


How can I fix this?

Sounds like someone was playing around in the Form1.designer.cs file. That's a no no. The designer files are reserved for the exclusive use the Visual Studio forms designer, and you should not touch them.
But maybe I'm a little too harsh. Since the move to Core, the Winforms system hasn't been quite as, let's say "robust"... as it once was, and this kind of thing seems to happen on it's own from time to time now 
To fix it, you'll need to remove the method and all references to it from your code. Then use the Visual Studio designer to re-add it.
This demonstrates (one reason) why it's important to have source control, even for small personal projects. Visual Studio will need to do it's thing to re-add the method (reverting doesn't always help), but having source control gives you the body of the method and tells you where calls to it are made, so you can recover effectively.

This error means that the event handler method button1_Click associated with the Click event of button button1 is not found in your Form1. To fix this problem, follow these steps:
1: Find the line button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click); in the Form1.Designer.cs file. If this line of code is not there, you can add it manually, or double-click the button in the VS designer, which will automatically generate the event handler.
2: Check if the event handler exists: In your Form1.cs file, confirm that the button1_Click event handler method has been defined. It should look like this:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Your logic code
}

If this method is not there, you need to add it manually.
3: Sometimes Visual Studio may have a temporary cache problem. Try to clean the project by Build -> Clean Solution, and then Rebuild again to see if the problem is solved.
